# Laravel collection map method to flatten multi-dimensional

Tags: arrays, laravel, dictionary, collections

I have this code and i want rename collection to different key & value.
But when i use `map` method the value return to they existing `key` and i want remove the key to flattens multi-dimensional collection using map `method`

Retrieve model:

```
$user = User::find(123)->orderByDesc('created_at')->get()->pluck('name', 'id');

$data = $user->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return [
        'id'   => $key,
        'text' => $value,
    ];
});
```

Expected result:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'text' => 'Shinka Nibutani',
    ], [
        'id' => 2,
        'text' => 'Kashiwagi Rein',
    ], [
        'id' => 1,
        'text' => 'Alice Zuberg',
    ],
]
```

Actual Result:

```
$data = [
    3 => [
        'id' => 3,
        'text' => 'Shinka Nibutani',
    ],

    2 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'text' => 'Kashiwagi Rein',
    ],

    3 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'text' => 'Alice Zuberg',
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add values() at the end. Something like that:

```
$data = $user->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return [
        'id'   => $key,
        'text' => $value,
    ];
})->values();
```

Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-values

values()

The values method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers:

```
$collection = collect([
    10 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    11 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]
]);

$values = $collection->values();

$values->all();

/*
    [
        0 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
        1 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]
*/
```